# How to find index of sublist without class C#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexof

I want to find the index of sublist in list `route` which contains certain value(i), but I don't want to make a class of it.
Here is my code:

```
var route = new List<List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i<DC1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<DC1; ++j)
    {   
        if (routeopt.x[0, j] == 1)
        {
            List<int> subroute = new List<int>();                        

            if (routeopt.x[i, j] == 1)
            { 
                subroute.Add(j);
                route.Add(subroute);
            }
        }
    }

    if(i == 0) continue;

    for (int j = 1; j<DC1;j++ )
    {
        if (routeopt.x[i, j] == 1)
        route[route.IndexOf(i)].Add ( j);
    }
}

foreach (var subroute in route)
{
    Console.Write("subroute: ");
    foreach (int s in subroute)
        Console.Write(s + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

For example, based on this code:

```
for (int j = 1; j < DC1;j++ )
{
     if (routeopt.x[i, j] == 1)
     route[route.IndexOf(i)].Add(j);
}
```

I want to make if `x[1,3] == 1` then I can add 3 to sublist which contains 1.
this code `route.IndexOf(i)` is still get red underline, please help how to correct it. Thanks

Comment: Try `routeopt.x[i][j]`

Comment: @Mairaj in which part should I try that? because I already stated that routeopt.x is double array [i,j] not [ ][ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `Single` method to retrieve the specific list you want given a predicate `Contains(i)`. Here I am looking for the list that contains 6, and adds 7 to it.

```
 var routes = new List<List<int>>()
 {
   new List<int>() {1, 2, 3},
   new List<int>() {4, 5, 6},   
 };

 List<int> targetList = routes.Single(i => i.Contains(6));
 targetList.Add(7);
```

To get specifically the index of that list, then you can use `IndexOf` method like:

```
 int targetListIndex = routes.IndexOf(targetList); // 1 in this example
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from an *example* (which we turn into a *test* later):

```
 List<List<int>> route = new List<List<int>>() {
   new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // sublist #0: contains value == 4
   new List<int>() {7, 8, 2, 9},    // sublist #1: doesn't contain value == 4
   new List<int>() {9, 10, 4},      // sublist #2: contains value == 4
 };
```

and we are looking for `value` within each of sublists

```
 int value = 4;
```

finally, we want to have sublist indexes as the outcome: `0` and `2`.
If it's your case, I suggest using *Linq*

```
List<List<int>> route = new List<List<int>>() {
  new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
  new List<int>() {7, 8, 2, 9},    
  new List<int>() {9, 10, 4}, 
};

int value = 4;

var indexesFound = route
  .Select((sublist, index) => new { // eh, new class, but anonymous one
     sublist = sublist,
     index = index, }) 
  .Where(chunk => chunk.sublist.Contains(value))
  .Select(chunk => chunk.index)
  .ToArray(); // if you want, say, array materialization
```

Test

```
Console.Wrire(string.Join(", ", indexesFound));
```

Outcome:

```
0, 2
```

**Edit:** if you want to have just one index, you have to specify which one, e.g. for the very first index put `.First()` instead of `.ToArray()`:

```
int firstIndexFound = route
  .Select((sublist, index) => new { // eh, new class, but anonymous one
     sublist = sublist,
     index = index, }) 
  .Where(chunk => chunk.sublist.Contains(value))
  .Select(chunk => chunk.index)
  .First(); // or .Last()
```

Comment: your code still get error, you cannot use `var. It said 'Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement'

Comment: @Arlita Nurmaya Asri: Oh! But I can use `var`; I've copied and pasted the code from my Visual Studio and it does work. You can change `var` to `int[]` however.

Comment: I already did that, but the error still the same. Is it different if the var result is only `int` instead of `int []`? Because I want to make it as an index later

Comment: @Arlita Nurmaya Asri: yes, it's the reason for the error. Let's rename my `result` into, say, `indexesFound`

Comment: Your code is worked, but I want the index as `int` not `int[]`, so I can make it as index of my list

Comment: @Arlita Nurmaya Asri: in *general case* you have got many indexes; if  you want just *one* of them, you have to specify - are you looking for the *first*, *last*, some *other*?

Comment: Actually in my problem it would be unique value in each sublist, so it only result in one specific index. but if you want me to specify, the last or first is the same

Comment: @ArlitaNurmayaAsri use `.Single()` then.